# update nested object in Mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs to update a mongodb collection and i'm using nested objects like this :

```
school
 *name
 *adress
 - class
 *name
 *type
 -student 
   *name
   *gender
   *age
```

I got a simple form for student in order to edit it, and after clicking update , I need to add  parent object  e.g school.class.student.$.gender;

Any idea how to transform this :

```
{ "name" : "brad" }
```

to

```
{ "school.class.student.$.name" : "brad" }
```

Thanks.

here is my nodejs model sample :

```
module.exports.updateStudent = function(schoolid, classid, studentid, student, options, callback) {
    let query = {
        'schoolid': schoolid,
        'school.classid' = classid,
        'school.class.student.studentid': studentid
    };
    //
    let update = { $set: {}};
    //
    update.$set =  student;

    r.update(query, update, option, callback);
};
```

And student object is :

```
student : {
  gender: 'Male',
  age: 19
}
```

It should be transformed to :

```
student : {
  'school.class.student.$.gender': 'Male',
  'school.class.student.$.age': 19
}
```

before submitted to update.

Comment: Is the student an array?

Comment: yes indeed , school + class + student are all array

Comment: can you upload one sample that will be easy to understand?

Comment: question updated